# Actionresult not returning correct error code

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-functions, actionresult

I am implementing a custom business exception and returns the exception using `BadRequestObjectResult`.

## exception throw

```
throw new BusinessException(Int32.Parse(AppConstants.ErrorCodes.DeviceNotFound), "Device not found.");
```

## catch block

```
    catch (BusinessException ex)
    {

        return (ActionResult)new BadRequestObjectResult(ex);
    }
```

But it always returns an internal server error (code 500)

The value in the object at the catch block shows the correct error code which is passed from the throw part.

[image: Values of variable ex at catch block]